# Highcharts Data Parsing List of lists

Tags: django, highcharts

I'm using Django and I am trying to parse the data I am putting into my template to load into high charts.

This is the first I'm using High Charts and I was unable to locate a way of parsing it this way.

Right now my data is presented like

```
[["Date", "Product1", "Product2"],["Dec 28 2017", 2, 2], ["Dec 29 2017", 2, 2]]
```

How do I make a column chart where the bars are under each day.

Thanks

Comment: is your data static? you could consider loading it from a JSON file in the template

Comment: This documentation page explains how to format your data: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize your data, and need to give a format.
Below is the format of hightcharts columns.

```
data: [{
    x: 1,
    y: 9,
    name: "Point2",
    color: "#00FF00"
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 6,
    name: "Point1",
    color: "#FF00FF"
}]
```